# Grub Splash options

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2

A clean install of **Ubuntu 12.10** on a laptop (from server CD, and then ***xubuntu-desktop package***) works well.  However, during boot there are sometimes text messages:

How do I change this so that no text messages scroll during boot?

Is that `quiet splash` in `/etc/default/grub` and then run `sudo update-grub`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and found a working solution (for me). Original information from this blog: http://jechem.blogspot.be/2011/04/fix-plymouth-splash-screen-in-ubuntu-on.html

First install hwinfo by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install v86d hwinfo
```

After the installation run the following command and note down the highest resolution:

```
sudo hwinfo --framebuffer
```

For me this was **Mode 0x0361: 1280x800 (+5120), 24 bits**, next edit the following file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

This will open the GRUB config file, we now look for **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"** and change it with the following, change your resolution with mine and also add the color depth (for me 24 could be 16 or 32).

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x800-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
```

Then find the following line (uncomment if needed) and change your resolution again, note that you don't include the color depth:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800
```

Save and exit, next edit the following file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

Scroll to the end of the file and add the following line, again add your resolution and the colordepth like you did before:

```
uvesafb mode_option=1280x800-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap
```

Then in the terminal type the following commands and then reboot:

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

For me this fixed the problem, I tried all the other suggestions and scripts, none of them worked but this does, good luck!